# bad rtp pt 101 (expecting 8)

Tags: sip, pjsip, dtmf

I use pjproject on a rapsberry pi to make calls. The call is working but when I use DTMF keys like '*' or '#', I catch the error in the title "bad rtp pt 101 (expecting 8)". I understood that it means tel-events are going through the audio media but is not correctly interpreted. The version of pjproject used is 2.14.

[Output of pjsip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wuq0A.png)

I tried to change the configuration of pjproject multiple times but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

According to the SDP offer in the capture, 101 and 102 are provided but the sample frequency is bizarre for 101 (48000), however the 102 frequency is correct (8000) and the peer consider  it should be 102.

In the first place, I do no think this offer is semantically correct and the answer is missing for further investigation.